# What is the principle ? When Spark deal with data bigger than memory capacity?

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

As I know , Spark use memory to cache the data and then compute the data in memory.But what if the data is bigger than memory?
I could read the source code ,but I don't know which class do the schedule job?
Or could you explain the principle of how Spark deal with this question?

Comment: We're (probably) not the developers of Spark. Why don't you ask their developer?

Comment: @Raptor 1) you doesn't need to be the developer to know such vital details 2) What makes you think that Spark developers is a special kind of developers who do not hangout on stackoverflow (and especially, do not monitor questions on their tag)?

Comment: [The answer can be found here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/scala-programming-guide.html#rdd-persistence)

Answer (score 0):

om-nom-nom gave the answer, but only as a comment for some reason, so I thought I'd post it as an actual answer:

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/scala-programming-guide.html#rdd-persistence